# Is node.js capable of reading from URL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, v8

What I am trying to achieve is to create script which will read from URL and then use this data to do some manipulations.

In example. This script will run every 5 minutes, load page from somewhere, check if something changed, and if something did change (there is one small particular change I am actually will be looking for, but it doesn't matter, as the idea stays the same), it will send me an alert by email.
Question is. Can Node.js handle that?

I can create this script in ruby, or even as shell script, run from crontab on server every N minutes; but I wanted to try out Node.js, and it sounds like I have a good "pet project" to try it on.

Comment: What's the small change you're looking for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. look at the "request" module for node.js.  It is basically an http client which you can use from inside your node.js app. See https://github.com/mikeal/request

Comment: And what would be the best way of loading data from some site every N minutes? Do for(..) kind of cycle inside node.js script, or just run it from the crontab? Just curious when could I gain more perfomance improvement.

Comment: I think you might want to look at javascript setTimeout() and clearTimeout(). Rune these inside a loop.