# Read file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, filesystems, readfile

Is it possible to read a file from url in node.js. I used fs.readFileSync but it can be used only for reading a file from path. Any help on this will be really helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is node.js capable of reading from URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124105/is-node-js-capable-of-reading-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

mikeal's [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) allows for very simple downloading of remote documents.

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://example.com/yourdoc.txt', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body)
    }
})
```